# First order differential equations - issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I understand the existence and uniqueness theorem as follows:

Let $\dot{x}=F(t,x)$ and $F'_x(t,x)$ be continuous on a rectangle $\Gamma$, and let $(t_0,x_0)$ be points (of our initial value problem) inside $\Gamma$. Then, there exists exactly one local solution passing through $(t_0,x_0)$.
The rectangle $\Gamma$ is defined as:

$\Gamma=\{(t,x):|t-t_0| \le a, |x-x_0| \le b\}$, where $a,b>0$ are constants.

If these conditions are met, there exists a unique solution for our initial value problem, that might only exist for an interval smaller than $(t_0-a,t_0+a)$.

Indeed, defining $M= max_{(t,x) \in \Gamma} |F(t,x)|$, and $r=min \{ a,b/M \}$, our initial value problem has a unique solution on $(t_0 - r, t_0 +r)$

Now, by considering the following initial value problem:

$\dot{x}=x^2$, and $x(0)=1$,

there exists a unique solution because $x^2$ is continuous everywhere (existence), and $2x$ is still continuous everywhere(uniqueness). Thus, these two functions are trivially continuous around $(0,1)$.

The particular solution yields: $x(t)= \frac{1}{1-t}$, which exists for all $t \in(- \infty,1)$.

However, if I look at the theorem, I always expect a solution symmetric around $t_0$, i.e. $(t_0 - r, t_0 +r)$. Why is this not the case?

Update:
[image]

Source:
Knut Sydsaeter, Peter Hammond,Atle Seierstad, - Further Mathematics for Economic Analysis (2009)

Comment: Your particular solution does not verify the initial condition. $x(t)=\frac{-1}{t-1}$ does.

Comment: The theorem doesn't really claim that $(t_0-r,t_0+r)$ is the *maximal* interval of existence.

Comment: @HansLundmark. I see, I've misunderstood the theorem. I infer the theorem says $(t_0-r,t_0+r)$ is an interval of existence, but nothing is said about its maximum length. I guess the maximum interval of existence for the initial value problem can be inferred by looking at where the particular solution is defined